# Validating various conditions

Tags: vba, excel

I have put together some code that will go through some data in a sheet named 'test' to check the following:

(1) confirm if there is an error in column 2.
(2) confirm if there is a false in column 3.
(3) confirm if there is a blank in the range defined (from A1 to last row in C).

It will then give you a message box telling you what the issue is.

Code is:

```
Sub check()

Dim y As Long, i As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim chkAA As Boolean, chkTEP As Boolean, chkNULL As Boolean
Dim row As Range, rng As Range, cell As Range

LastRow = Sheets("test").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
Set rng = Sheets("Test").Range("A1:C" & LastRow)
Dim output As Integer

chkAA = True
chkTEP = True
chkNULL = True

For y = 1 To Rows.Count
     If IsError(Sheets("Test").Cells(y, 2).Value) Then
          chkAA = False
          Exit For
     End If
Next y

For i = 1 To Rows.Count
     If Sheets(“Test”).Cells(i, 3).Value = "False" Then
          chkTEP = False
          Exit For
     End If
Next i

For Each row In rng.Rows
  For Each cell In row.Cells
    If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
      chkNULL = False
    End If
  Next cell
Next row



If chkAA = True And chkTEP = True And chkNULL = True Then
output = MsgBox("Validation complete", vbInformation, "Validation")
ElseIf chkAA = False And chkTEP = True And chkNULL = True Then
output = MsgBox("Double check your AA numbers", vbCritical, "Validation")
ElseIf chkAA = True And chkTEP = False And chkNULL = True Then
output = MsgBox("Double check your TEP combination", vbCritical, "Validation")
ElseIf chkAA = True And chkTEP = True And chkNULL = False Then
output = MsgBox("There is a blank cell", vbCritical, "Validation")
ElseIf chkAA = False And chkTEP = False And chkNULL = True Then
output = MsgBox("Double check your AA numbers and TEP combination", vbCritical, "Validation")
ElseIf chkAA = False And chkTEP = True And chkNULL = False Then
output = MsgBox("Double check your AA numbers and do not leave blanks", vbCritical, "Validation")
ElseIf chkAA = True And chkTEP = False And chkNULL = False Then
output = MsgBox("Double check your TEP combination and do not leave blanks", vbCritical, "Validation")
Else: chkAA = False And chkTEP = False And chkNULL = False:
output = MsgBox("Please make sure spreadhseet is filled correctly", vbCritical, "Validation")
End If

End Sub
```

It gives me an error that it is out of range.

Can you please advise me where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Why bother with LastRow and rng if you are going to ignore them and run down to the last row of the worksheet using For y = 1 To Rows.Count ?

Comment: @Jeeped The LastRow and rng is for the 3rd validation check.

Comment: What line gives the error?

Comment: @urdearboy This line (  If Sheets(“Test”).Cells(i, 3).Value = "False" Then)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sheets("Test")`

Just try re-typing out this line and re-run.

**Edit**

As Jeeped pointed out, the issue was the type of quote used. Note the subtle difference below:

> ” & "

Comment: How weird. Thanks!

Comment: Those were 'smart quotes' wrapping Test. e.g `“` and `”` . Good eye!

Answer (score 2):

Now that you have removed the 'smart quotes' from wrapping the worksheet name, if you have to check every cell in a column, it would be best to avoid looping through 1,048,576 rows.

```
with workSheets("Test")
    'check for errors
    if not .Columns("B").specialcells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors) is nothing then _
        chkAA = False
    'check for "False"
    if not .Columns("C").find(what:="false", lookat:=xlwhole, matchcase:=false) is nothing then _
        chkTEP = False
    'check for blank cells
    if not .rng.specialcells(xlCellTypeBlanks) is nothing then _
        chkNULL = False
end if
```

Additionally, it may read easier if you were to apply some sort of XOR bitwise logic to achieve your announced results.

```
dim chk as long
with workSheets("Test")
    'check for errors
    if not .Columns("B").specialcells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors) is nothing then _
        chk = chk+1
    'check for "False"
    if not .Columns("C").find(what:="false", lookat:=xlwhole, matchcase:=false) is nothing then _
        chk = chk+2
    'check for blank cells
    if not .rng.specialcells(xlCellTypeBlanks) is nothing then _
        chk = chk+4
end if

select case chk
    case 0    'none
      output = MsgBox("Validation complete", vbInformation, "Validation")
    case 1    'errors
      output = MsgBox("Double check your AA numbers", vbCritical, "Validation")
    case 2    'falses
      output = MsgBox("Double check your TEP combination", vbCritical, "Validation")
    case 3    'errors and falses
      output = MsgBox("Double check your AA numbers and TEP combination", vbCritical, "Validation")
    case 4    'blanks
      output = MsgBox("There is a blank cell", vbCritical, "Validation")
    case 5    'errors and blanks
      output = MsgBox("Double check your AA numbers and do not leave blanks", vbCritical, "Validation")
    case 6    'falses and blanks
      output = MsgBox("Double check your TEP combination and do not leave blanks", vbCritical, "Validation")
    case 7    'errors, falses and blanks
      output = MsgBox("Please make sure spreadhseet is filled correctly", vbCritical, "Validation")
end select
```